# To override ToString() method with properties or fields?

Tags: c#, properties, field, overriding, tostring

- When should I override the ToString() method with class properties and when with fields?
- Is there only one way valid or both are?
- If both are ok, in which cases should we use each of the ways?

  ```
  public override string ToString()
  {
     return String.Format("{0},{1}", this.field1, this.field2);
     // ..or
     return String.Format("{0},{1}", this.Property1, this.Property2);
  }
  ```

Please help???

Answer (score 2):

Either are acceptable.

However, one thing to consider is that properties are more generally accepted as "public-facing" whereas fields are typically considered "private" by most C# developers.

As a result, if you wanted to be able to call `.ToString()` on internal values that aren't modified directly, use fields (and keep them private).  If you are fine with them being modified externally and those externally modified values being returned via `.ToString()`, use properties.

Finally, if you needed to do any sort of additional "logic" on the property value before returning it, a property would be preferable since you can modify it in the property's `getter`.

Comment: What does this have to do with the values being modified?  The implementation that uses the properties is only using the getter and it's possible the properties are read only.

Comment: @juharr what happens if the properties are set via constructor and then modified later?  That would change expected behavior and wouldn't be possible with a field approach (sans reflection).  It's possible the properties are NOT read only...there isn't enough detail in the question to tell.  The point is about proper encapsulation of behavior and avoiding unintended side effects.  It may or may not be relevant, which is why I called it out.

Comment: OK, so from all of your answers, I understand that both ways are actually possible, but in terms of which one to choose in a special case, depends entirely on the means of the class functionality in the program. Thank you for the attention on this issue! I cannot vote for best answer yet, since I'm too new here.. Cheers!

Comment: @CSharp4eto You can't vote, but you can accept the answer that helped you the most.  If it isn't mine, you should select another.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, You should override ToString method, when you want to return a string you prepared specially. It's not a reuirement.

- Both ways are ok, although using properties is highly recommended because you will have more of a control over the return values.

Answer (score 1):

If getter contains some logic, e.g. it uses field's value to calculate result, then use property. As a user of your class I'd be surprised to see different values in UI (if I used property directly) and in stack trace if I used ToString().

*Edited:* By default classes should not provide instance fields that are public or protected. So I'd recommend you to avoid using fields in ToString() when properies are available, because you may expose some sensitive data or incorrect object's state.

Answer (score 0):

Often, properties *represent* fields, e.g.

```
   // Property1 represent field1
   public String Property1 {
     get {
       if (null == field1)  
         return "[empty]"; // <- more readable 

       return field1;
     }
   }
```

and that's why *properties* often are more *readable* and thus, IMHO, preferable; however, fields are also a good choice (especially if there's no property that wraps the field).

```
  // Terse C# 6.0 syntax 
  public override string ToString() {
    return $"{Property1},{Property2}";
  }
```